# What exactly is the linear layer in the transformer model?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, transformer, attention-mechanism

Please see this image:
[image]

There are linear layers to modify the Query, key and value matrices and one linear layer after the multi head attention as they mention also from here:

[image]

Are these linear layers simply dense or fully connected layers? Let's consider the weight matrix W<sub>i</sub> <sup>Q</sup>. Does this represent a dense layer with "Q" nodes? As they are using matrices as input rather than 1D vectors, I am getting a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the original Transformer article](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf), these linear layers are just matrix multiplications.

As described in the paragraph you referred to in your question $W^Q$ is a matrix of dimensions $d_{model} \times d_k$, that is, it is a fully connected layer with $d_k$ units.

In practical implementations, these have the optional addition of a bias vector. You can see their actual definition in [the fairseq code](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/modules/multihead_attention.py#L65).

Comment: In that case, are the weights of the linear layer same for each row of Q?

Comment: Yes, for each attention head, the same $W^Q_i$ is applied to all query vectors in $Q$.

Comment: Thank you for all the help :)